# Google Search Appliances

Tags: google-search-appliance

How to customize the xml output of Google Search applianes.We need to add images and ratings in the search result.By default after crawling, when we go for search, the items on the indexes it is not proving all the details users needed.How to cutomize or extend the searh result with Google Search appliances.

Answer (score 0):

If this information is in the metadata of the indexed documents but isn't being displayed in the XML of results when you remove the proxystylesheet URL parameter, try adding getfields=* as a URL parameter.